# Generar una alerta si hay error en la consola de windows

Tags: alert

Me gustaria saber si se puede mostrar una alerta en la pagina si hay un error en la consola del navegador, y si no lo hay que no muestre nada. Como detecto si hay un error para que la muestre?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch)

Answer (score 2):

En general puedes capturar los errores de Javascript usando `try{ ...} catch(error) { ... }`, pero esto no captura los errores de carga, por ejemplo.

Una solución que permite capturar más errores es añadir un listener a `window`, pero ni siquiera de este modo capturarás todos los errores: Temas como problemas de CORS o similares, relacionados con seguridad, pueden no capturarse.

Intentar espiar a los métodos de `console` tampoco funciona siempre, ya que estos métodos sólo son llamados desde Javascript, los mensajes de error del navegador pueden ser enviados usando código "nativo" que se salta este API:

```js
window.addEventListener('error', event => {
  if (event.error) {
    console.log("Un error", event.error.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Un error capturado: " ,event.target);
  }
},true);


var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://www.google.com/img/inventaddos";
var src = document.body;
src.appendChild(img);

let error = console.error;
console.error = function (...params) {
  error(...params);
  console.log("Error llamado con el mensaje", ...params);
}
console.error("Mandando un error a consola");
falla()
```